# File permissions: parent folder has 100% control of all children, children can't do anything

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Here's my current structure:

```
script.py
apps/
|-generated-folder-1/
  |- [files]
|- generated-folder-2/
  |- [files]
|- generated-folder-3/
  |- [files]
```

How do I set up permissions so that script.py (which is kicked off via a POST; I can't really use `sudo` or anything like that) has permissions to create new folders and modify anything inside those folders, however the files inside each folder are 100% sandboxed?

Each generated folder is a git checkout (done by script.py), from random people. I do my best to ensure no rogue files will be checked out, but I'm worried it's potentially possible a .php file or something might slip past me. In that case, I don't want it to have the ability to touch anything outside its own folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If script.py does not run with root permissions, you could simply change the owner of the folders you do *not* want changed...

If there are more complicated requirements, let script.py only write to a staging area and have another script do a vetted copy...